# Setup Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I try to setup the Hyperledger Fabric project. Unfortunately,  when I invoke **vargant up** I get:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
 ==> default: Box 'hyperledger/fabric-baseimage' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: 0.0.10
The box 'hyperledger/fabric-baseimage' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I tried to use docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-baseimage/ but run command didn't do anything

I would like to start Fabric Blockchain, try management system, deploy contract and initiate some test transactions. Could anyone help me, how to start Fabric?

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to follow this sample for fabric setup. first, as is, then do your changes.
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

Answer (score 3):

The error listed here is pretty clear and provides a link to the resolution. Vagrant is unable to download the image because the local CA did not carry the certificate of the CA that issued the HashiCorp server's certificate.

If you are interested in simply running the Hyperledger Fabric and developing/deploying chaincode and developing a blockchain application, you can simply run `docker-compose up` with the following docker-compose.yml definition using Docker for Mac or Windows (beta):

```
vp:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  ports:
  - "5000:5000"
  environment:
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.1:2375
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  command: peer node start
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc
```

The Vagrant-based development environment approach to getting the Fabric running on your laptop is really more oriented towards developers wishing to help with the development OF the Hyperledger Fabric project than it is for those who simply wish to develop applications using the platform.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to install again.

1. vagrant destroy. It will stops and deletes all traces of the vagrant machine.
2. vagrant up. starts and provisions the vagrant environment.

Comment: Thanks. I run vagrant global-status and received: "There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer". Have I to prepare my PC before run vagran up? On vagran destroy I received "VM not created"

Comment: are you sure your vagrant is running OK? or just install vagrant again ? https://www.vagrantup.com/

Comment: Issue was with SSL certificate. I added config.vm.box_download_insecure = true to Vagrantfile
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try these instructions:
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv.html

I used branch v0.6 of the hyperledger fabric from GitHub instead of
the Gerrit one (at step "Cloning the Fabric project"):
git clone -b v0.6 https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric.git

When the VM provisioning will be complete at the end, you will have an environment ready to be used for testing chaincode.

When the environment is complete, you should also check out the GitHub IBM-Blockchain marbles app.

Hope this works out for you, good luck.

Answer (score -2):

Open this link: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hyperledger/boxes/fabric-baseimage

Use command below:

```
vagrant init hyperledger/fabric-baseimage; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```